# Individually check the truth value for array elements

Tags: python, numpy

My code is:-

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    if x<=0.5:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
        
X=np.array([0.1,0.2,0.6,0.5,0.01,1])
print(f(X))
```

This code gives an error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

but I don't know how `a.any()` or `a.all()` will be useful for me. I want the output to be:-

```
[0,0,1,0,0,1]
```

I can use the `for` loop, but is there any shortcut syntax so that I get the desired output in just one go?

Comment: The easiest would be `np.where(X<=0.5, 0, 1)`. See the docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vectorize` - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: X=np.array([0.1,0.2,0.6,0.5,0.01,1])

In [3]: f = lambda x: 0 if x<=0.5 else 1

In [4]: func = np.vectorize(f)

In [5]: func(X)
Out[5]: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

OR

`where` - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

```
In [7]: np.where(X<=0.5, 0,1)
Out[7]: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```